# Репликация SQL. Разные размеры баз

Tags: sql, sql-server

Настройл репликацию транзацкии между двумя серверами.
Всё проходит без ошибок, но огромная разница в размерах базы на master и slave серверах.

**Размер Master базы:**
[image: Размер Master базы]

**Размер Slave базы:**
[image: Размер Slave базы]

Разница почти в **16 раз**.

В чём может быть проблема? Не могу понять, в какую сторону необходимо копать?

Comment: Каким образом Вы происзводите синхронизацию?

Comment: Настроил репликацию Transactional publication (push) в SQL Server 2014. Или вас что-то другое интересует?

Comment: А Вы все объекты синхронизируете? Посмотрите стандартный отчет по занимаемому топ таблицами месту для обеих баз, может увидите что-то очевидное сразу

Comment: а каким образом размер базы может влиять на репликацию!
а Вы смотрели что за данные лижат в базе?